# Write binary file chunk

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have 6GB free physical memory. Im working with a big data, with a size around 4GB. I have just realised that i cant save it the way, i used to do it with smaller data(~1GB):

```
void save(char f_name[], int size, float data[])
{
    std::fstream f_bin(f_name, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

    f_bin.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    f_bin.write((char*)data, size*sizeof(float));
    f_bin.close();
}
```

becouse it takes the data in memory and it needs the same amount of RAM to write it to the HD. Is there a way to write the 4GB in (e.g. 1GB) chunks, so it will never exceed the 6GB limit?

Comment: I wonder whether the need to have the same amount of RAM is platform specific.

Comment: First off, I assume you're on a 64-bit platform? Second, physical RAM doesn't really matter, as the OS will use the HDD for extra virtual memory if it needs it. What OS are you using?

Comment: im on Cygwin_4.x-Windows 64bit

Comment: Depending how you're generating the data a memory-mapped file could work for you.

Comment: the data is a flatten out float array

Comment: What error did you see with the code above?

Comment: no error. if i try to write a file bigger than free memory/2, it produces a 0 byte file. if the size of my data smaller, it works as aspected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something to the effect of

```
void save(char f_name[], int size, float data[])
{
    std::fstream f_bin(f_name, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

    f_bin.seekp(std::ios::beg);

    while (size > 0)
    {
        int amount  = std::min(1000, size);
        f_bin.write((char*)data, amount * sizeof(float));

        data += amount;
        size -= amount;
    }

    f_bin.close();
}
```